# ObjectBox: Get notified only when query with condition has changed items

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, objectbox

Let's say I have a box of items, with some properties on them. I then want to receive only certain items, that match some condition, so I create an `RxQuery` like this:

```
val query = filesBox.query()
    .equal(File_.completed, true)
    .build()

RxQuery.observable(query).subscribe(...)
```

Now this query does indeed return all of the items that match that condition. However, when that table is updated, I always get a "notification" / onNext signal, even if the changed items do not match my query.

So if I have some files with `completed = true` and I add a new file with `completed = false`, the query will trigger, but return the same items as it did previously.

Is there a way around this? I know I could do `distinctUntillChanged()` as part of the Rx flow, but I want to hopefully find some way to do it with ObjectBox that's more efficient.

Comment: Behind the scenes ObjectBox subscribes to changes for an entity type, not for a specific property. I'm not sure there is a way around this behavior right now. https://docs.objectbox.io/data-observers-and-rx

Comment: Ah bummer. Thanks for the info. You might want to change the docs, it's a bit ambiguous imo: `Combining queries and observers results in a convenient and powerful tool: query observers will automatically deliver fresh results whenever relevant data has changed.`. This is what made me think it would be possible, the "relevant data" part.

Comment: Thanks, will update the web docs. The subscribe method documentation is more explicit about it: http://objectbox.io/files/objectbox-java/current/io/objectbox/query/Query.html#subscribe-- But if using RxQuery you never saw that...